# Jquery inside PHP class

Tags: php, jquery, api

I need to post some XML to an API on our network via php.  Usually I would use Curl to do this which I know works well but the server my scripts run from doesnt have curl and without going into all the detail it cannot be installed as it breaks some other important production app on the server.

After some thought I was hoping to post my XML via jquery to the API.  I was wondering if anyone knoew if it was possible to access jquery from within a PHP class?  I know it sounds crazy and im sure someone will tell me why I shouldnt do this but to me it sounds like a reasonable solution.

Othwerwise I might have to go though the class and try and pull the xml back to the controller and page that uses the class to send the XML.

P.S  we have tried command line curl to solve our issue which does work however we get an issue with URL length on some requests as the XML can be very large and too long to pass via url.

Any thoughts?

Comment: http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/3220360.htm try this ...

Comment: thanks fo rthis im going to try it now  ^^

Comment: A not so pretty solution but to get round this we have created a new db table on the server that creates the xml and basically creates a row in the table with the xml.  we then using command line curl(not php curl) we send the api the id of the row we have inserted.  the api then loads the xml out of the database , parses and returns a response.

Comment: it has too many points of failure for a permanent solution but we need somethign workingo for monday so it will do for now and work towards a better solution on our dev copy next week.  ^^ thanks to all people who took the time to help =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [sockets](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) instead.

Copied from the link @Val posted:

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp)
{
echo 'Could not open connection.';
}
else
{
$xmlpacket ='<?XML version="1.0"?>
<Your_XML>
</Your_XML>';

$contentlength = strlen($xmlpacket);

$out = "POST /script_name.php HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$out .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
$out .= "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n";
$out .= "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$out .= "Content-length: $contentlength\r\n\r\n";
$out .= "XML=$xmlpacket";

fwrite($fp, $out);
while (!feof($fp))
{
$theOutput .= fgets($fp, 128);
}
fclose($fp);

// $theOutput is the response returned from the remote script
}
?>
```

Comment: tgank you for you response.  I did try this method however if gave us fsockopen erros.  about not being able to open the requested url even though we could visit the url fine ina browser.  The good news on the other hand is I did find a solution whichisnt great but does work for now which I'll explain above.

Comment: even though we didnt use this solution it does look to be the best solution to get around the issue im facing.  So Im going to accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. jQuery runs in the browser at the client not on the server. You can send Javascript to the client and do your stuff there. But with [file_put_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) you can also send data to another side, if it accepts it per GET.